# Visual Studio Code unit test marked with question mark, no matter what the result is

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, xunit

In Visual Studio Code, I have a specific unit test that **no matter what the result is** - is marked with a question mark.

I added other tests and they behave as expected (marked with either a green tick or red x).

What does the question mark mean ?
[image]

```
[Fact]
public async Task LinuxHelper_ExecuteInvalidCommandBash_ShouldFail()
{
    //arrange
    
    //act
    //var bashExecutionResult = LinuxHelper.RunAsBash(@"dasda");
    
    //assert
    10.Should().Be(11);
    //bashExecutionResult.Succeeded.Should().BeFalse();
    //bashExecutionResult.Error.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    //bashExecutionResult.ExitCode.Should().NotBe(0);
}
```

Using `C#`, `.NET Core Test Explorer` VSC extension, with `xUnit` and `FluentAssertions`.

Comment: what is your language, looks C#, and which test runner do you use?

Comment: @rioV8: `c#`,.`NET Core Test Explorer` extension, using `xUnit` with `FluentAssertions`

Comment: Using C# and XUnit in JetBrains Rider IDE, the question mark means that the unit test was not executed.  Perhaps it has the same meaning in VS Code? More info - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Executing_Analyzing_Tests.html#analyzing

Answer (score 3):

For me this occurred when I hadn't set a glob pattern for the Dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath setting, and had multiple test projects in my solution. Once I set that option to **/*.Test.csproj it could manage the results from running all of the tests.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the .NET Core Test Explorer (C#, xUnit). The issue only occurred for me when using xUnit's 'DisplayName' parameter.

Changing `[Fact(DisplayName="Passing an invalid date throws an exception.")` to `[Fact]` resolved the problem for me.